# ASP.NET MVC Model is not populating

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am binding Model to the view and its working fine when populating the view but on post back its not sending any data to controllers

```
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult InfoNext(MyModel ModelDep)
        {
```

In the aspx view i am binding properly

```
<%@ Page Title="Information" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Some.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyModel>" %>
```

Issue is ModelDep is not having any updated values from View

Comment: Will need the model class and the view contents to have an understanding of why it may not be happening.

Comment: Because your `POST` data doesn't match the layout of `MyModel`. Unfortunately, you haven't shown us either one, so I can't help you fix it. Please show both the `POST` (from Fiddler or Firebug) and the definition of `MyModel`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyModels>"
```

should be:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyModel>"
```